# How can I use plot_coupling_map from a CouplingMap object in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

Qiskit has a [`plot_coupling_map`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.visualization.plot_coupling_map) option for visualizing coupling maps however, I want to be able to use it from a [`CouplingMap`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.transpiler.CouplingMap#get_edges) object instead of the provided `CouplingMap.draw()` (which uses graphviz).

The `plot_coupling_map` requires `num_qbits`, `qubit_coordinates` and `coupling_map`. I see how I can get the `num_qbits` (`CouplingMap.size()`) and the `coupling_map` is just the `CouplingMap`, but I don't see an easy way to get the `qubit_coords`. Do I have to generate them each time I want to plot it?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not mentioned in the documentation, `None` is a valid value for `qubit_coordinates`. So, the below code snippet should work without any issue with Qiskit version 1.0

```python
coupling_map = CouplingMap.from_grid(3, 3)
plot_coupling_map(
    coupling_map.size(),
    qubit_coordinates=None,
    coupling_map=coupling_map.get_edges()
)
```

The result:

[image]